# perl regex extraction based on condition

Tags: regex, perl

I am working on a framework and I have to get some regex expressions but was stuck at this point.

```
Execution start time 09/13/2013 02:43:55 pm

[Case-Url] - www.google.com


[Req-URL ] - www.qtp.com


***Passed***
__________________________________________________________

[Case-Url] - www.yahoo.com


[Req-URL ] - www.msn.com


***Passed***

___________________________________________________________

[Case-Url] - www.google.com


[Req-URL ] - www.qtp.com


***Failed***
```

In the above test results, I have to fetch the [Case-URL] and [Req-URL] for the Passed and Failed test cases . How do I get only the Case-URL and Req-URL for the passed results?

Answer (score 1):

Regexes are not terribly appropriate here. Instead, split your input into chunks which you parse individually:

```
use strict; use warnings; use feature 'say';

<DATA>; # discard first line;
# set record separator
local $/ = "__________________________________________________________\n";
while (my $chunk = <DATA>) {
  my ($case, $req, $statusline) = split /\n/, $chunk;
  # possibly parse $case and $req further here
  if ($statusline =~ /Passed/) {
    say for $case, $req;
  }
}

__DATA__
Execution start time 09/13/2013 02:43:55 pm
[Case-Url] - www.google.com
[Req-URL ] - www.qtp.com
***Passed***
__________________________________________________________
[Case-Url] - www.yahoo.com
[Req-URL ] - www.msn.com
***Passed***
___________________________________________________________
[Case-Url] - www.google.com
[Req-URL ] - www.qtp.com
***Failed***
```

Output would be:

```
[Case-Url] - www.google.com
[Req-URL ] - www.qtp.com
[Case-Url] - www.yahoo.com
[Req-URL ] - www.msn.com
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the reply. We are almost close but I have like 1000's of Case-Urls and Req-Url's and the above code displays all the lines from the input file which has these url's.
I tried the following code ;

while( my $temp = <FILE>){
my($case,$req,$status) = split /\n/,$temp;
print "$case\n";
}

But it displays all the lines and just not the first 2 case and req URL's ..

Comment: @ankitdhebar My code works for me, I do not know what input you are using. Note that I only print out the URLs **if** the `$status` contains `/Passed`. Your snippet does not contain this conditional!

Answer (score 0):

This will extract the failed cases. You can then extract Case-Url and Req-Url from `$fifo[0]` and  `$fifo[3]` easily . Same can be done for Passed cases.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

my @fifo=('') x 7; # Initialize an empty array with size = 7 (Message Block Size)
open(FILE,"temp.txt");

while(<FILE>)
{
    push(@fifo,$_);       # Add element to the end of array making its size 6  
    shift @fifo;          # Remove first element reverting its size back to 5  
    if($fifo[6]=~/Failed/) # Check if 7th line of block has Failed in it 
    {
        print @fifo;
    }
}
close(FILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The suitability of regex for this particular application aside, here is a regex that will capture the passed URLs:

```
\([Case-Url\] - .*)\n+(\[Req-URL \] - (.*)\n+\*{3}Passed\*{3}
```

I couldn't get this work with in Perl mode in regexplanet, but you can see it in action at Rubular [here](http://rubular.com/r/tMUWVOrXhO)